# Increase rate at which samples are taken from AudioRecord

Tags: java, android, audiorecord

Hey so I am trying to record data from the audio device and graph it. It is recording from a piezo that outputs in the 16khz to 19khz range. Below I will have the relevant code. My current issue is that the data isnt be calculated or read at a fast enough rate. I am no sound engineer and a lot of the FFT work was just pulled from multiple resources.

here is a picture of what I am talking about. As you can see I am getting 1 datapoint from the first R wave in the qrs complex. At first I was getting one. Then I changed my min buffer size * 500 and that seemed to give me two datapoints. I would like to have several in the really short amount of time to get an accurate reading.

TLDR: what do i change to make is so I can get more frequency readings per second.

https://dl2.pushbulletusercontent.com/mugoZmNLGtbCta4Si5Pu4RUdJOgMqILK/Screenshot_20160705-094146.png

and my code...
the buffer is being added to a list that has already been declared. The FFT method I am using takes a short[]

```
public int audioSource = MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC;
public int channelConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
public int audioEncoding = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
public AudioRecord audioRecord = null;
public int blockSize = 256;                               // deal with this many samples at a time
public int sampleRate = 44100;                             // Sample rate in Hz

    public void audioRecordLoop() throws Exception {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.e(TAG, "start audioRecordLoop");

            int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig, audioEncoding);
            audioRecord = new AudioRecord(audioSource, sampleRate, channelConfig, audioEncoding, bufferSize * 500);

            if (audioRecord.getState() != AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED) {
                Log.e(TAG, "AudioRecord init failed");
                return;
            }
            final short[] buffer = new short[blockSize];
            audioRecord.startRecording();
            int len = 0;
            while (isRecording == true) {
                len = audioRecord.read(buffer, 0, blockSize);
                shortList.add(buffer);
                if (len < 0) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "read error " + len);
                    return;
                }
            }
            if (audioRecord != null)
                audioRecord.release();
        }
    }).start();

}
```

to calculate

```
 public void calcFrequency() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            FrequencyScanner frequencyScanner = new FrequencyScanner();
            while (isRecording) {
                if (shortList != null && shortList.size() > 0) {
                    short[] shorts = shortList.get(0);
                    final double frequencys = frequencyScanner.extractFrequency(shorts, sampleRate);
                    frequencyList.add(frequencys);
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

then to graph

```
public void graphFrequenecy() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (isRecording) {
                try {
                    if (frequencyList != null && frequencyList.size() > 0) {
                        final double frequency = frequencyList.get(0);
                        if (frequency > 13000) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "run: " + frequency);
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    series.appendData(new DataPoint(series.getHighestValueX() + 1, frequency), true, 3000);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        frequencyList.remove(0);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```